# I want to compare two versions of data from a table using JAVA and display the differences on a UI.What can be the best way to approach this?

Tags: java, sql

For example,say I have a table A which has a primary_key **a1** and corresponding version is **1**.There is a history table corresponding to A say,**A_History**.This contains a record with same primary_key **a1**, but a different version,say **2**. I will be given as input,the primary_key(**a1**) and two version numbers(**1** and **2**).I have to compare (**using JAVA**) the values of all attributes of the table for both the versions and display the non-matching records on a UI.

Comment: You can use lots of tools for this, but it would be good to know if you are using any available framework, such as Hibernate, or if you already have some code. If you don't have anything, you should try to do it before posting the question and, then, refer to a particular question you might find.

Comment: I am planning to use hibernate,but have not come up with anycode as of now.I am confused about how to start.

Comment: Try using an example like this one http://blog.sencide.com/2011/03/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners.html. Try to replicate it and then modify it to suit your needs (an equals implementation of the class A would be enough). If you find any problems along the way, show us your code and somebody will be glad to help you.

Comment: I am aware of hibernate setup,I was looking for some kind of algorithm/flowchart as I am finding it difficult to come up with the logic.

Comment: you can write a sql to do that. And then implement the sql in java using hibernate

Comment: Sorry, but that question is extremely vague...

Comment: I am thinking about creating a model class for the  2 tables,and then saving two objects corresponding to 2 version numbers,and then comparing the attributes ....will this logic work?

Comment: Yes, that is what you have to do. You have to create one object for each entry in the database and the compare them (with an equals() and a hashCode() that does not use the version number, for instance).